# Algorithms for Search tree vs building tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, breadth-first-search

say I want to have an algorithm which gets a solution as quick as possible, which consists of starting from a state in a tree, and going through all possible states in a tree-like strucutre, why would it be necessary to first build a tree, and then traverse it, instead of building a tree, and if during building a solution node has been found, to stop building and immediately backtrack to the root, noting down the path to this leaf?

Basically, is there an BF algorithm to 'generate' a tree Breadth-First, rather than creating a tree first, and then search through it in a breadth-first manner?

Kind of like the animated results [here:](http://www.davidrobles.net/blog/2015/01/31/generating-game-trees-using-depth-and-breadth-first-search/)

Thank you for reading

Comment: I was under the impression that the most common approach to tree searching is to build the tree implicitly as you go rather than building the whole tree and then searching it. Do you have a source that says otherwise?

Comment: Well, my professor said that in order to search a tree, you first need to have built a tree. Now I am in conflict on what searching a tree means

Comment: It sounds like either (1) they referring to a different sort of problem, (2) they were referring to the abstract idea of there being a tree rather than the code for building it, or (3) they were mistaken. It's uncommon in search problems like these to explicitly construct the tree beforehand for precisely the reason you identified.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage in a search algorithm to build a tree and then search it, exactly due to the reasons you have mentioned. Furthermore, there is no search-related advantage that is gained by building a tree breadth-first or depth-first.

Usually, there are trees already present and we traverse them using the Breadth-First approach or the Depth-First approach. The reason why we choose one of these approaches is due to a property of the search-element or of the tree.

If you have seen cases where we construct a tree and then search it, it's for pedagogical purposes where you have to write a standalone program that constructs the tree and then traverses it. This is similar to creating a linked-list of numbers and performing a linear search, or constructing a Binary-Search-Tree and then searching for a value. Typically this approach tends to teach about creation and traversal of a data-structure packaged into one program.